# Detect release / debug in gulp using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, configuration, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-2015

I've set up an ASP.NET 5 project in Visual Studio and created a gulpfile.js which I use to build my typescript and less files.

For release builds, I want to uglify and concat my javascripts, and for debug I want to include my typescript- and maps in my output folder.

Is there a way to 'tell' gulp the current configuration? I've seen some mention of setting the NODE_ENV environment variable, but thus far the solutions I've seen arent optimal; they require using the command line before starting the IDE, etc.

The closest solution I've seen is here: http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/gulp--workaround-for-handling-vs-solution-configuration

This does, however, mean that I can no longer utilize the Task Runner Explorer which is built-in in the IDE

Comment: [Here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Modern-Web-Development-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2015-with-Mads-Kristensen#c635546297464916269) is the only word I found on this, but it's back from Dec.

Comment: How are you running gulp when you want a dev or production build? Do you want to be able to do both of them inside Visual Studio?

Comment: @AdamBotley I want a way to let my gulp script to detect the current configuration settings in visual studio, most importantly debug or release. Right now I have several gulp tasks which does different build configurations, e.g. build-debug and build-release. Problem is I have to run them manually depending on the build I want, rather than just binding it to the 'after build' binding in task runner explorer. The optimal solution; an extended binding system where you could specify conditions in addition to events; e.g; After build + deubg; run build-debug. After build + release, build build-rel

Comment: @AdamBotley [cont] Since the optimal solution for some reason has been left out by Microsoft (would've been so easy to implement), I would want a way to assign the current configuration into a variable and write my build tasks accordingly, e.g. if (debug) /* compile source maps */

Comment: @havardhu honestly I think the [link you posted above](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/gulp--workaround-for-handling-vs-solution-configuration) is going to be the best solution until/if Microsoft provide an easier way to hook into your build configuration from the Task Runner Explorer.

Answer (score 11):

I know this has been around for awhile but I recently ran into the same issue and was unhappy with the other solutions and workarounds that I found in answers here on SO. I found a very nice solution that we went with in the comments on the aspnet github page: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1231#issuecomment-182017985

I hope that it helps someone get to a solution they're happier with faster than I did.

Simply, add the following line to your pre-build event in project config

```
echo {"config" : "$(ConfigurationName)"} > ../buildConfig.json
```

With that little beauty sitting around you can read it in your tasks and react accordingly.  I use it to prevent minifying files when I'm in debug mode like so:

```
gulp.task("min:js:bundlesFolder", function ()
    {
        var json = fs.readFileSync("./buildConfig.json", "utf8");
        var host = JSON.parse(json.replace(/^\uFEFF/, ''));
        host.isDebug = host.config == "Debug";
        console.log(host.isDebug);
        if (host.isDebug === true)
        {
            return;
        }
        return gulp.src([paths.jsbundleFolder + "/**/*.js", "!" + paths.jsbundleFolder + "/**/*.min.js"])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsbundleFolder));
    });
```

Comment: You can also use the **$(ProjectDir)** macro to help build the _json_ file path. For example:

   `echo {"config" : "$(ConfigurationName)"} > "$(ProjectDir)buildConfig.json`

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio 2015, with the gulp integration, I like @edo limburg and @RamenChef's answer the best.

I have a single page angular app in the same solution as my web api.
When building the SPA, I just wanted to replace the URLs to the API and OAuth2 (OIDC) authority servers in an html and a couple of JavaScript files.

I created a gulpfile.js with both a Debug and Release task. Note the case-sensitive spelling:

```
gulp.task('Debug', function () { 
 gulp.src("./callback.html")
    .pipe(replace(uatAuthority,
                    debugAuthority))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
...
}
gulp.task('Release', function () {
 gulp.src("./callback.html")
    .pipe(replace(debugAuthority,
                    uatAuthority))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
)
}
```

FYI, I included gulp-string-replace to handle the replace tasks:

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');
```

After I tested the tasks in the Task Runner Explorer, I unloaded the project file and edited it, adding the following code right before the end project tag:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="gulp $(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Nice post, complete and working as expected. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio,

- create a new console project
- Install the nugget package 'MSBuild.NodeTools' in your project
- Unload your .csproj file and edit it by adding the line in the after build target

  ```
     <Target Name="AfterBuild">
         <MSBuild.Gulp   GulpFile="path to your gulpfile"/>   
     </Target>
  ```

Here there is all property you can use :

- **GulpFile**: Path to gulpfile. Defaults to $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\gulpfile.[js|coffee].
- **GulpWorkingDirectory**: Directory in which context the gulp task gets executed. Defaults to $(MSBuildProjectDirectory).
- **GulpBuildTask**: Gulp task that gets executed on build. Defaults to build-$(Configuration).
- **GulpCleanTask**: Gulp task that gets executed on clean. Defaults to unset.

As you can see the task executed takes the name of the configuration in visual studio, so if you build your project in "debug", the task "build-debug" will be executed

You can also doing like this, if you want a custom task :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<MSBuild.Gulp  Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'"  GulpFile="path to your gulpfile"  GulpBuildTask="CustomDebug"/>
<MSBuild.Gulp  Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'"  GulpFile="path to your gulpfile"  GulpBuildTask="CustomRelease"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: This is a preprocessor directive which would work in C#, but unfortunately this does not work with gulp, which is just a javascript, in this case executed by the IDE via the Task Runner Explorer

Comment: Ok, so i add an 'EDIT' part in my answer, tell me if it fit with your question

Comment: This looks interesting. Although it doesnt really use the built-in Task Runner Explorer, it still enables me to specify which gulp-script to run. I am going to give it a try later. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you're using Visual Studio and your project template is a *Blank App (Apache Cordova)* and you cannot see any *Build Events* when you right-click on *ProjectName* in Solution Explorer and go to Properties like below:

[image: Project Properties]

You can then manage your Solution Configuration using **Cordova hooks**.
These are the special scripts injected in your solution to customize cordova commands and are executed with your solution activities/events. For more information, see [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/).

Steps to follow:

1. In the root directory of your project, create a new folder (say, 'hooks') containing the hook javascript file (say 'solutionConfigHook.js') as follows:

   ```
   "use strict";

   // function to run the '_default' task in 'gulpfile.js'
   // based on solution configuration (DEBUG or RELEASE) prior to building the solution
   module.exports = function (context) {
       var config = getConfig(context.cmdLine);
       if (!config) {
           console.log('Unable to determine build environment!');
           return;
       }
       else {
           var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
           console.log('Runnung Gulp tasks now...');

           // 'solutionConfig' is the command line argument for config value passed to the gulpfile
           // '_default' is the task name in *gulpfile.js* that will have access to 'solutionConfig'
           var gulpCommand = 'gulp _default --solutionConfig ' + config.toString(); 
           console.log(gulpCommand);

           child = exec(gulpCommand, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
               console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
               console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
               if (error !== null) {
                   console.log('exec error: ' + error);
               }
           });
       }
   }    

   // function to get the solution configuration using CLI
   function getConfig(cmdLine) {
       var matches = /--configuration (\w+)/.exec(cmdLine);
       if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
           return matches[1];
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
2. Add this hook in your *config.xml* file as follows for each platform against the desired hook type.

   (For your reference, the code snipped here is for windows platform alone and is called for 'before_build' hook type.)

   ```
   <platform name="android">
       ... // other resources or attributes
       <hook src="hooks/solutionConfigHook.js" type="before_build" />
   </platform>
   ```
3. In your *gulpfile.js*, remove the binding of the task(s) by either deleting the reference on top or by going to the *Task Runner Explorer* and then right-clicking each task and unchecking all bindings.
4. Add a task in your *gulpfile.js* that will be called by the hook itself on the activity defined as hook type in *config.xml*.

   ```
   gulp.task('_default', function (solutionConfig) {
       if (solutionConfig == "Release") {
           // perform desired task here
       }
       else if (solutionConfig == "Debug" {
           // perform desired task here
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am entirely new to npm, grunt or gulp. However, I think that I found a simple solution using pre-build events.

Add the following line to your pre-build event command line in the project that contains the grunt (or gulp) files:

```
npm update && grunt $(ConfigurationName)
```

Now as long as you have grunt tasks with the same name as your build configuration, you should be all set.

```
grunt.registerTask('Debug', ['sass', 'concat']);
grunt.registerTask('Release', ['sass', 'concat', 'cssmin', 'removelogging', 'uglify']);
```

You'll need the usual pre-requisites on the machine that is running the build. Remember to restart VS after installing all of this stuff. Visual Studio needs to be run as Administrator in order to execute all all grunt tasks

- Visual Studio Extenstions - Search for and install through Tools -> Extensions and Updates:

  - Node JS Tools
  - Web Essentials
- NPM - https://nodejs.org/en/download/
- Ruby - Installer found here http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

  - IMPORTANT: In the installer check off "Add Ruby Executables To Your PATH"
- Grunt and Sass - Both of these are installed through command prompt (Run as admin)

  - `gem install sass`
  - `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: Does this apply to gulp though?

Comment: It should work the same way with gulp.task('Debug', function() { ... )};

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found:

1. Get your grunt/gulp tasks running using the Task Runner Explorer first by following this guide. Do not set any bindings though.

grunt - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-grunt

gulp - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-gulp

2. Create Debug and Release grunt/gulp tasks.
3. Once running with the Task Runner Explorer, copy the command that Visual Studio uses to run your task from the output window of Task Runner Explorer. (Ignore the bindings, do not set these)

[image: Task Runner Screenshot]

4. Change the paths so that they are relative to the bin folder, and to work with whichever mode is set in Visual Studio. From the image above, you would change the command to:

`cmd.exe /c gulp -b ".\.." --color --gulpfile ".\..\Gulpfile.js" $(ConfigurationName)`

5. Paste this command as a pre-build task in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Exec Build task to run a gulp task:

```xml
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
   <Exec Command="gulp beforeBuild --c $(Configuration) --p $(Platform)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that allows you to pass the configuration as a flag to your gulp task, instead of running the configuration as the task itself. This would allow you to use [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) to trigger different procedures from within the task.

**Note:** This answer assumes that gulp isn't installed globally.

1. Install gulp as a dev dependency

   ```
   npm install gulp --save-dev
   ```
2. Register gulp as an npm script

   ```
   {
       "name": "vs-build-test",
       ...
       "scripts": {
           "gulp": "gulp"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Install [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to handle custom flags

   ```
   npm install yargs --save-dev
   ```
4. Require yargs in `gulpfiles.js` with a default for the `configuration` flag

   ```
   var argv = require('yargs').default('configuration', 'Debug').argv
   ```
5. Create a build task in `gulpfile.js`

   ```
   gulp.task('build', function () {
       console.log(`Build Configuration: ${argv.configuration}`);
   });
   ```
6. Add a pre-build event to run gulp `[Project Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-build Event]`

   ```
   cmd.exe /c npm run gulp build -- --configuration $(ConfigurationName)
   ```

---

The reason this can be useful is so that you can use the same tasks but conditionally run only portions of the process. Take for example a task that builds javascript:

```
gulp.task('build:js', function () {
    let isProduction = ${argv.configuration} === 'Release';

    ...

    return gulp.src(source)
            .pipe(gulpif(!isProduction, sourcemaps.init()))
            .pipe(concat(outputFile, { newLine: ';' }))
            .pipe(gulpif(isProduction, closure(closureFlags)))
            .pipe(gulpif(!isProduction, sourcemaps.write()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(basePath));
});
```