# How can I get current configuration (Debug/Release) of VS15 in gulpfile.js?

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2015, gulp-uglify

I've wrote a task to minify my .js files.

Now, I want to conditionally uglify them (do it if in release, don't if in debug), 
based on the configuration mode of VS15, e.g.  [image].

Is there any variable which is accessible from the gruntfile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect release / debug in gulp using Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712324/detect-release-debug-in-gulp-using-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: View the detailed solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335232/7452548

Answer (score 3):

```
set NODE_ENV=$(ConfigurationName)
gulp
```

This row will let you read which build symbol is used in Visual Studio when compiling your solution. To access this variable you can use process.env.NODE_ENV.
So we can use this piece of code to check if we are compiling in Debug or Release mode and then decide if we should run the minifying task or not.

```
var tasksToRun = ['scripts'];
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'Release'){
    tasksToRun.push('minify');
}
gulp.task('default', tasksToRun);
```

http://www.myeyeson.net/gulp-js-and-browserify-with-asp-net/

Comment: gulp doesn't wnat to run from my command line... so it errors