# .NET Core - How to copy files on build based on build type

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In a .NET project, I was able to selectively copy files on build like so:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
xcopy $(SolutionDir)\myProject\wwwroot\shared\app.constants.debug.js $(SolutionDir)\myProject\wwwroot\shared\app.constants.js /Y
)
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
xcopy $(SolutionDir)\myProject\wwwroot\shared\app.constants.release.js $(SolutionDir)\myProject\wwwroot\shared\app.constants.js /Y
)
```

I want to do the same in .NET Core.

In my project.json, I'm trying the following, but nothing happens:

```
"scripts": {
            "precompile": [
                "if $(%compile:Configuration%) == Debug ( xcopy %project:Directory%\\wwwroot\\shared\\app.constants.debug.js %project:Directory%\\wwwroot\\shared\\app.constants.js /Y ) if $(%compile:Configuration%) == Release ( xcopy %project:Directory%\\wwwroot\\shared\\app.constants.release.js %project:Directory%\\wwwroot\\shared\\app.constants.js /Y )" ],
                "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
    }
```

Anecdotally, `"precompile": [ "echo TEST" ]` fails, but `"precompile": [ "android avd" ]` starts the virtual device manager successfully, so I'm not sure if it's a problem with my setup.

I've also tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39837587/852806), but can't get anything working.

How can I do it please?

Comment: project.json is going away. VS 2017 only supports MSBuild so maybe instead of fighting with project.json you could convert your project to *.csproj. As a side note your you should not need to use condition to copy... `xcopy $(SolutionDir)\myProject\wwwroot\shared\app.constants.$(ConfigurationName).js $(SolutionDir)\myProject\wwwroot\shared\app.constants.js /Y`